# Login to Site using Httpwebrequest vb.net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I want to log in a site using a simple code of `vb.net` 
using `httpwebrequest` ,

i have create a simple code but already he give me login failed but the information are tru !!

```
Using req As New HttpRequest
        req.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent
        req.Cookies = New CookieDictionary(False)
        req.Proxy = Nothing
        req.IgnoreProtocolErrors = True

        req.AddParam("username", tmail.Text)
        req.AddParam("password", Tpass.Text)

        Dim respo As String = req.Post("https://picsart.com/sign-in").ToString
        If respo.Contains("Logout") Then

            MsgBox("Login Done!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Login Or Password Incorrect", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End If

    End Using
```

and below the http record using `live http header` firefox addon

```
https://picsart.com/sign-in

POST /sign-in HTTP/1.1
Host: picsart.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101             
Firefox/56.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: https://picsart.com/
Content-Length: 106
Cookie: sid=
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
username=myemail&password=mypass&nextUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fpicsart.com%2F%23
HTTP/2.0 200 OK
```

Comment: @Gino Mempin  A Web Form login failed returns `StatusCode = 200` because the login page is reloaded. A successful login returns `StatusCode = 302` (Found) + redirection to the landing page.

Comment: This is not a `WebRequest`. If you're using a custom class, you should specify what that is and what is doing with this `CookieDictionary`,  `AddParam()`, `Post()` etc..

Comment: @Jimi can you give me a example about web request ?